# how do I make sigpack to find armadillo?

Tags: c++, cmake, header, armadillo

I am currently trying to get [`sigpack`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) to find [`armadillo`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) using cmake.  Including armadillo does not seem to be a problem, as I can include it using `find_package()`, but for some reason can `sigpack` not find it.

`sigpack` is a header only library, for which the way I've included it to my project, is by moving the header files to my project, and manually include them in the cmake, which I am bit uncertain whether it is correctly done, or if it could have been otherwise.

```
MESSAGE(“In spectogram CMAKELIST”)
MESSAGE( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/base/base.h" )


SET(HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/base/base.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fftw/fftw.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/base/base.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filter/filter.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gplot/gplot.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/image/image.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/kalman/kalman.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/parser/parser.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resampling/resampling.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/spectrum/spectrum.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/timing/timing.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/window/window.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sigpack.h
    )

find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(spectogram STATIC spectogram.cpp spectogram.h ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(spectogram PUBLIC ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(spectogram PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_features(spectogram PUBLIC cxx_defaulted_functions)

MESSAGE(“out spectogram CMAKELIST”)
```

The code what currently is giving me a error is this class definition:

```
#pragma once

#include "sigpack.h"
class spectogram {
private:
    int m_var{ 23 };

public:
    void set_var(int value);
    int  get_var() const;
};
```

This code currently give me error message :

```
 error: ‘arma_inline’ does not name a type
     arma_inline double sinc( double x )
```

Which might be because sigpack cant see armadillo? how do i do that?

This compiles:

```
#pragma once

#include <armadillo>
//#include <sigpack.h>  sigpack.h cant see armadillo?

class spectogram {
private:
    int m_var{ 23 };
    arma::mat somethind;
public:
    void set_var(int value);
    int  get_var() const;
};
```

Comment: Looks like headers in subdirectories (like `base/base.h`) are not intended to be included *directly*. Use `#include <sigpack.h>` instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried that.. same problem there..

Comment: Strange: `sigpack.h` firstly includes `armadillo`, which in turn defines `arma_inline` macro.

Comment: yeah... Even weirder is that I can `#include <armadillo>` in the class definition code without any problem, but when it is done inside `sigpack.h`, will problem occur.

Comment: Have you got armadillo from [here](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code)?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be linked with `sigpack.h` but the fact that each header file within each subdirectory (example `base/base.h`) haven't included `<armadillo>` thus doesn't know the existence of the namespace `arma::`

Comment: I apt-get installed `armadillo`

Comment: As I have said, headers in subdirectories are not intended to be included directly. They should be included via `sigpack.h`, which includes armadillo.

Comment: I have only included `sigpack.h` in the header code, but for some weird reason is this file only not able to see the `#include <armadillo>`  while the header in which the class is defined (located in the same directory) sees `<armadillo>` without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

sigpack depends on armadillo version>7,8...  and apt-get install version 4,... So ended with downloading the tar from the website.

`cmake . && make && sudo make install`

and my project was able to find the correct header file.